# How to run grep inside awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

Suppose I have a file `input.txt` with few columns and few rows, the first column is the key, and a directory `dir` with files which contain some of these keys. I want to find all lines in the files in `dir` which contain these key words. At first I tried to run the command

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print $1}' | xargs grep dir
```

This doesn't work because it thinks the keys are paths on my file system. Next I tried something like

```
cat input.txt | awk '{system("grep -rn dir $1")}'
```

But this didn't work either, eventually I have to admit that even this doesn't work

```
cat input.txt | awk '{system("echo $1")}'
```

After I tried to use `\` to escape the white space and the `$` sign, I came here to ask for your advice, any ideas?

Of course I can do something like

```
for x in `cat input.txt` ; do grep -rn $x dir ; done
```

This is not good enough, because it takes two commands, but I want only one. This also shows why `xargs` doesn't work, the parameter is not the last argument

Comment: Run `cat input.txt | awk '{print $1}'` and check, if it gives you everything you need to pass to grep.

Comment: `cat input.txt | awk '{print $1}'` works perfectly fine - it will give all the key words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt | xargs -n 1 -I pattern grep -rn pattern dir
```

Comment: I think you were the first to show `-I` option but I have to say that I prefer using `%` rather than `pattern`

Comment: @e271p314 that's personal choice! I prefer more readable command

Comment: It does indeed, and when I see "pattern" I think I'm looking at example code, whereas `%` is obviously something else.  As jkshah said, personal choice.

Answer (score 28):

You don't need `grep` with `awk`, and you don't need `cat` to open files:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{keys[$1]; next} {for (key in keys) if ($0 ~ key) {print FILENAME, $0; next} }' input.txt dir/*
```

Nor do you need xargs, or shell loops or anything else - just one simple awk command does it all.

If input.txt is not a file, then tweak the above to:

```
real_input_generating_command |
awk 'NR==FNR{keys[$1]; next} {for (key in keys) if ($0 ~ key) {print FILENAME, $0; next} }' - dir/*
```

All it's doing is creating an array of keys from the first file (or input stream) and then looking for each key from that array in every file in the dir directory.

Comment: **+1** ... This is much cleaner than anything the rest of us have come up with.

Comment: I believe it can't work for *recursive grep*. Or am I missing something? I really like single awk but for this requirement, I would say xargs and grep makes it more readable and flexible.

Comment: I think this is very good but I'm afraid I don't understand this. In any case, unfortunately, it doesn't work, I guess because I didn't tell you that `input.txt` is not a file but an output of some other sequence of piped commands.

Comment: @jkshah - no but then recursive grep is a terrible idea and the GNU guys who introduced it should have their keyboards taken away as they must've forgotten the UNIX mantra that every tool should do one thing and do it well. There's a perfectly good tool to find files and it has a very obvious name. If a recursive search is required to find files then that's the tool that should be used to do it, not grep whose name is also derived from it's purpose - Globally search for a Regular Expression within a file and Print the match.

Comment: @e271p314 - correct, if there is no real file named input.txt then you can't pass a file named input.txt as an argument to the command. I've updated my answer to show how to use input from a pipe.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work, the output contains lines without keys from the real_input_generating_command

Comment: @e271p314 That's not possible given my understanding of your question so far so please update your question to show some brief sample input and expected output along with the erroneous output you're seeing.

Comment: +1. And to adress the comment about the recursivity in subdirs of "dir/": the end of the awk command could replace `dir/*` with `$(find dir/ -type f -print)` [providing there are not files with spaces in them, etc].. but it could be less portable (files with special names) and also invokes an extra "find" (but this could be more efficient than shell's expansion)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Good one. it completes the solution.

Comment: $ cat dir1/file.xml | grep Tag | tr -d '<' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I % grep -rn % dir/ | wc -l

15010

$ cat dir1/file.xml | grep Tag | tr -d '<' | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/tmp.txt ; for x in `cat /tmp/tmp.txt` ; do grep -rn $x dir/ >> /tmp/tmp1.txt ; done ; wc -l /tmp/tmp1.txt

15010

$ cat dir1/file.xml | grep Tag | tr -d '<' | awk 'NR==FNR{keys[$1]; next} {for (key in keys) if ($0 ~ key) {print FILENAME, $0; next} }' - dir/* | wc -l

1214

and I got many unrelated messages "awk: cmd. line:1: warning: command line argument `dir/tmp' is a directory: skipped"

Comment: @EdMorton I would not want to argue on whether `grep -r` is good idea or not. My only point was provided solution was incomplete for the requirement of recursive search. `find` definitely is appropriate tool for it and *@OlivierDulac* demonstrates the solution with it. cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't write the output in the correct format, but basically the two phase command I suggested in the question and the command jkshah and ghoti suggested gave the same amount of output while yours got only 10% so and printed many error messages for every directory inside `dir`

Comment: @e271p314: the error messages jsut tell you that awk will (correctly) ignore directories along the way. replacing `dir/*` by `$(find dir/ -type f)` will prevent this but at the risk of introducing errors if the files are named with special caractersr and/or have space/tabs in them...

Comment: Bottom line jkshah's and ghoti's answers are the shortest and at least to me are much clearer than this answer although I'm sure it can work with a bit of effort

Comment: @EdMorton My completely subjective opinion: Ed, you are a genius :-) Thank you for sharing your experience !

Answer (score 4):

First thing you should do is research [this](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Next ... you don't need to grep inside awk. That's completely redundant.  It's like ... stuffing your turkey with .. a turkey.

Awk can process input and do "grep" like things itself, without the need to launch the grep command.  But you don't even need to do this.  Adapting your first example:

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt | xargs -n 1 -I % grep % dir
```

This uses xargs' `-I` option to put xargs' input into a different place on the command line it runs.  In FreeBSD or OSX, you would use a `-J` option instead.

But I prefer your for loop idea, converted into a while loop:

```
while read key junk; do grep -rn "$key" dir ; done < input.txt
```

Comment: Actually this is very close to what I was looking for you just forgot `grep -rn`

Comment: I based it on the first example from your question which also didn't include the `-rn`.

Comment: So the thing is that as far as I'm concerned both you and jkshah deserve the credit. Since he has less reputation than you, I accepted his answer in order to distribute reputations evenly, but your answer is great too.

Comment: @e271p314 I would like to mention that *reputation* should not be a focus while determining better answer. I believe we do respond on SO not for reputation but for knowledge sharing. Any accepted ans should be ok as long as it worked for OP. Rep just confirms answer as genuine.

Answer (score 2):

Use process substitution to create a keyword "file" that you can pass to `grep` via the `-f` option:

```
grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' input.txt) dir/*
```

This will search each file in `dir` for lines containing keywords printed by the `awk` command. It's equivalent to

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt > tmp.txt
grep -f tmp.txt dir/*
```

Comment: Good answer, just need to emphasis that `<` and `(` must not be separated. Your answer is even a little better than the one I already accepted in the sense it outputs no duplicated results unlike the answers with `xargs -n 1 -I`

Answer (score 1):

grep requires parameters in order: [what to search] [where to search]. You need to merge keys received from awk and pass them to grep using the \| regexp operator.
For example:

```
arturcz@szczaw:/tmp/s$ cat words.txt 
foo
bar
fubar
foobaz
arturcz@szczaw:/tmp/s$ grep 'foo\|baz' words.txt 
foo
foobaz
```

Finally, you will finish with:

```
grep `commands|to|prepare|a|keywords|list` directory
```

Comment: How to generate the list? it's possible but not completely trivial. As I mentioned in the other posts, the input is not in a file but it's the output of a piped commands sequence. I used `tr '\n' '|'` on the output of `awk` but this always gives me `|` in the end of the string which I have to manually remove. I also think that you might want to try `egrep` instead of `grep` to avoid `\|`. All in all, your answer is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to use grep inside awk, make sure $1, $2 etc are outside quote.
eg. this works perfectly

```
cat file_having_query | awk '{system("grep " $1 " file_to_be_greped")}'
```

// notice the space after grep and before file name